# jquery image resize and rotator

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

what I am looking is for a jQuery plugin capable of rotating and resizing an image using handles, like in this `pic` ([this is the webapp](http://www.polyvore.com/cgi/app)). Working with jQueryUI rotating and resizing the same image is really messy and the image does not contain handles to click to rotate and move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

```
$('#theimage').rotateRight(45);
```

Answer (score 1):

To rotate, you might find [wilq32](http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222) to be a good starting point. Pretty simple syntax:

```
$("#image").rotate(-20);
```